# Cannot align h2 inside a div container to the right side

Tags: html, css, wordpress

please check this wordpress site: http://bit.ly/1FpV4Iy

I want to align the titles of articles with a thumbnail to the right side, but the title should stay over the thumbnail image.

I tried to float and textalign the h2 class, but it either didn't work or it showed the title  beneath the thumbnail image

How can I align the text to the right?

HTML code:

```
<h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="#" rel="bookmark">HATSUNE MIKU: PROJECT DIVA F EXTEND</a></h2>
```

CSS code

```
.entry-title { font-size: 36px; margin-right: 0px; }
```

Comment: please post the minimum code even in the question

Comment: Please avoid linking to external sites. Try creating a reduced test case using the inbuilt code snippet feature, or port it over to JSfiddle.

Comment: Ok I will in future. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **right: 0px;** in class **.postpreview h2.entry-title a**

Comment: this will just work for the first post. The second one doesnt work

Comment: Thank you, I am just wondering why margin-right:0px didn't work, but thanks